# Changing name of image control dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have multiple image controls in the page, and what I want is to change their sources dynamically from list of images, but I could not find any solution for the same.

Here is the code which I have used, but I cannot achieve the functionality.

```
<Image x:Name="image1" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_1" Stretch="None" Source="/Assets/default-placeholder.png" />

<Image x:Name="image2" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_2" Stretch="None" Source="/Assets/default-placeholder.png" />

<Image x:Name="image3" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_3" Stretch="None" Source="/Assets/default-placeholder.png" />
```

And here is a .cs file:

```
 string imgname = "image";
 int count = 1;

 foreach(PictureItem img in e.ChosenPhotoList){
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(img.ImageStream);
            Image i = new Image();
            imgname = imgname + ""+count+"";
            i.Name = imgname;
            i.Source = bitmap;
            //image1.Source = bitmap;
            imgname = "image";
            count++;
        }
```

In the code just above, if I directly use image control name for assigning source then it is working fine, but what I want is to change source name dynamically and assign source respectively.

If this is a wrong approach, and there is some other way to achieve the functionality then please share the same.

Answer (score 0):

I see three possible solutions:

**Option 1**
If it's always three images (or some other predefined amount), you can bind their source to properties in the code-behind:

Set the page as it's own `DataContext`

```
<Page
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    ...
    />
```

Make properties in the code-behind

```
public string Image1 { get; set; }
public string Image2 { get; set; }
public string Image3 { get; set; }
```

And then bind to them in your XAML

```
<Image x:Name="image1" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_1" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Image1}" />
<Image x:Name="image2" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_2" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Image2}" />
<Image x:Name="image3" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Loaded="image_Loaded_3" Stretch="None" Source="{Binding Image3}" />
```

**Option 2**
If you are showing dynamic amount of images, put them in some kind of ListView or similar list control and use the `ItemsSource` property to iterate through all the images and change their `Source` properties

**Option 3**
As a last resort you can try to use the VisualTreeHelper. This helper let's you navigate the visual tree at runtime. It should only be used as a last resort and it can be a bit difficult to use. You can see the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.ASPX) for more info. Also see this [old, but relevant guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in) on the VisualTreeHelper for info on how it works in practice.